# Prove $f(x)=(x-3)^2 +4$ is a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

for convex functions:
$$\lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2)\geq f(\lambda x_1 +(1-\lambda)x_2)$$
for $\lambda \in [0, 1]$
My solution looks like:
$$\lambda (x_1-3)^2 +4\lambda +(1-\lambda)((x-3)^2 +4)\ge\bigl(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 - 3)^2+4$$
 $$\lambda (x_1^2+9-6x_1)+4\lambda+(1-\lambda)(x_2^2+13-6x_2) \ge (\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2-3)^2 +4 $$
$$\lambda x_1^2 +x_2^2-\lambda x_2^2-6\lambda x_1-6\lambda x_2+13 \ge \lambda^2x_1^2+x_2^2+\lambda^2x_2^2-\lambda x_2^2+9+2\lambda x_1-2\lambda^2 x_2 x_1-6x_2+6\lambda x_2-6\lambda x_1$$
$$0 \ge\lambda x_1^2 - \lambda^2x_1^2 +\lambda^2x_2^2 +2\lambda x_1+12\lambda x_2 -2\lambda^2x_2x_1-4 $$

I am not sure if above solution is correct, but I could not figure out how to proceed from this point.

Comment: The first line of your solution must read $\lambda (x_1-3)^2 +4\lambda +(1-\lambda)((x-3)^2 +4)\ge\bigl(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 - 3)^2+4$ or $\lambda ((x_1-3)^2 +4) +(1-\lambda)((x-3)^2 +4)\ge\bigl(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 - 3)^2+4$

Comment: yes it should looks like i made a mistake in first step

Comment: No problem. Correct it and write down your new work.

Comment: Hint: prove that $g(x)=x^2$ is convex. Then prove that, in general, if $g(x)$ is convex then $f(x)=g(x-a) + b$ is also convex.

Comment: Sum of 2 convex functions is convex

Comment: @mfl I edited the steps accordingly

Comment: There is something wrong in your computation of $(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2-3)^2 +4.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that $$\lambda (x_1-3)^2 +4\lambda +(1-\lambda)(x_2-3)^2 +4-4\lambda \ge\bigl(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 - 3)^2+4.$$ That is,

$$\lambda (x_1-3)^2 +(1-\lambda)(x_2-3)^2 \ge\bigl(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 - 3)^2.$$  Equivalently
$$\lambda x_1^2+(1-\lambda)x_2^2-6\lambda x_1- 6(1-\lambda) x_2+9$$ $$\ge \lambda^2 x_1^2+(1-\lambda)^2 x_2^2+2\lambda(1-\lambda)x_1x_2-6\lambda x_1-6(1-\lambda)x_ 2+9$$

Simplifying, we arrive at

$$\lambda x_1^2+(1-\lambda)x_2^2+\ge \lambda^2 x_1^2+(1-\lambda)^2 x_2^2+2\lambda(1-\lambda)x_1x_2.$$ Arranging terms

$$\lambda(1-\lambda) x_1^2+\lambda(1-\lambda)x_2^2-2\lambda(1-\lambda)x_1x_2\ge 0.$$ This inequality is equivalent to

$$ \lambda(1-\lambda)(x_1-x_2)^2=\lambda(1-\lambda)(x_1^2+x_2^2-2x_1x_2)\ge 0,$$ which clearly holds.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use the second derivative

Comment: I want to do it without derivatives but looks like i am stuck in this equation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2)&=f(\lambda (x_1-3)+(1-\lambda )(x_2-3))\\\\
&=(\lambda (x_1-3)+(1-\lambda)(x_2-3))^2+4\\\\
&=(\lambda (x_1-3))^2+((1-\lambda)(x_2-3))^2\\\\
&+2\lambda (1-\lambda)(x_1-3)(x_2-3)+4 \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Furthermore, we can write

$$\lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2)=\lambda (x_1-3)^2+(1-\lambda)(x_2-3)^2+4 \tag 2$$

Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2)-f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2)&=\lambda (1-\lambda)(x_1-x_2)^2\\\\
&\ge 0
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Comment: its a good answer but i can not upvote because i am new here, less than 15 reputation.

Comment: I believe that you can up vote answers to your own posted questions.

Comment: it says my upvote is recorded but it is not displayed publicly.

Comment: Interesting.  You have 15 reputation points now.  I wonder if you try again, if the up vote will register.